# How can I load a very large raster (or portion of it) into R from an ArcGIS file geodatabase using R-Bridge (arcgisbinding)?

Tags: raster, r, file-geodatabase, import

I have a large raster stored in an ArcGIS geodatabase (dimensions: 105,000x260,000) that I am trying to load in R. I have tried the following:

```
library(arcgisbinding)
arc.check_product()

gdb <- "location_of_geodatabase"
layer <-"name_of_layer"

o <- arc.open(paste0(gdb, layer))
arcraster <- arc.raster(o)
raster <- as.raster(arcraster)
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in matrix(no_data_val, nrow = nrow * ncol, ncol = length(bands)) : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In nrow * ncol : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

I tried loading only a portion of the raster using the extent option for arc.raster(), but it resamples at a higher resolution keeping the dimensions the same. For example,

```
o <- arc.open(paste0(gdb, layer))

small_extent <- c(1384164 , 1536925 , 460645.2 , 647757)
arcraster <- arc.raster(o, extent=small_extent)

arcraster

type            : Raster
pixel_type      : F32 (32bit)
nrow            : 103000
ncol            : 265637
resample_type   : NearestNeighbor
cellsize        : 0.575071883824844, 1.81661923261566
```

I have read the documentation and I am not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: The ESRI FGD API limits raster raster size and bit depth, even through a bridge connection. However, do make sure that you are running the 64-bit version of R and not 32-bit as this influences import behavior as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran the same steps on 2 different rasters Y17_0_slope is 1mx1m (36944 columns by 83537 rows) and over 10 GB while INT_10m is 10m x10m (7390 columns by 16708 rows) and only about 500 MB

```
y17_slope_d <- arc.open(file.path(folder,'Y17_0_slope.tif'))

y17_slopea <- arc.raster(y17_slope_d)

y17_slope <- as.raster(y17_slopea)

int_e <- arc.open(file.path(folder, 'Int_10m_010722.tif'))

int_r <- arc.raster(int_e)

int <- as.raster(int_r)
```

I get the same error with the slope file as it is too large.  But the smaller (under 500 MB) file loaded without any issues.

At this point, I'm assuming it is a size issue. I don't know if it is RAM (500 MB vs 10 GB) or if it is the # of rows/columns.  But when it did load the smaller file, it  is listed as "Large RasterLayer(123472120 elements, 493.9MB)".